# looking for a phrase synonymous with 'pay it forward'

Tags: gratitude

I am looking for a phrase synonymous with 'pay it forward' so as to convey how expressing gratitude is a self-perpetuating concept.
I'd like to avoid anything too cliche.

Comment: How cliche is *too* cliche?

Comment: @Jim I would assume *other* Jim wants something *less* cliche than 'pay it forward'. Don't move to [Canada](https://www.thestar.com/news/canada/2012/12/31/tim_hortons_customers_pay_it_forward_228_times_in_winnipeg.html)?

Comment: Hi Jim (OP), I've added an answer but you're likely to get more (and better) answers if you edit your question to show words you've considered and rejected, as well as perhaps an example sentence for how you might want to use this word or phrase. You also might want to add some tags other than _gratitude_: _single-word-requests_, _phrase-requests_ and _idiom-requests_ are some suggestions. _single-word-requests_ have some quite specific rules, btw. Also worth a read is [this page](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), particularly the bits about research.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch - But any recognizable phrase might also be too cliche.  That leaves us new collocations.  And in that case, the question is too broad.

Comment: Is "one good turn deserves another" too cliche?

Answer (score 1):

You could use **virtuous circle** or **virtuous cycle**; these are like a *vicious circle* (or *cycle*) except that their effects are positive.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtuous_circle_and_vicious_circle):

> The terms **virtuous circle** and *vicious circle* (also referred to
>   as **virtuous cycle** and *vicious cycle*) refer to complex chains of
>   events that reinforce themselves through a *feedback loop.* **A
>   virtuous circle has favorable results, while a vicious circle has
>   detrimental results.**

(Emphasis in the quote is mine.)

The term is common enough to have made it into [several dictionaries](https://www.onelook.com/?w=virtuous+circle&ls=a) (more authoritative sources than Wikipedia, perhaps). For instance, [Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/virtuous_circle) gives the following definition:

> **virtuous circle** *noun*
>
> **A recurring cycle of events, the result of each one being to increase
>   the beneficial effect of the next.**
>
> ‘economic expansion would itself
>   produce a virtuous circle of increased productivity, increased
>   exports, and increased growth’

---

Just in case, it's worth mentioning that **positive feedback** is best avoided here, as it has connotations quite different to what you require; it can mean *a good reaction* or it can mean *"the enhancement or amplification of an effect by its own influence on the process that gives rise to it"*<sup>[1](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/positive_feedback)</sup> - not necessarily a good thing. Neither of these meanings are what you want on their own (although you are describing a ***positive** feedback loop*).